# How to find all tables containing column with name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I would like to query for names of all tables which contain column with name?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is with `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns`.  It is already a view that has this information:

```
select schema_name, table_name
from information_schema.columns
where column_name like '%name%';
```

If you want to remove duplicates, add `select distinct`.

Note that this works within a single database.

Answer (score 2):

Use system views

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name LIKE '%EmployeeID%'
ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
```

Comment: Those are views, not tables.

Comment: You should avoid using information schema views read here why [`The case against INFORMATION_SCHEMA views`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query on system views to get the tables' schema and name:

```
select QUOTENAME(s.name) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) from sys.tables t
inner join sys.schemas s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
where exists (
    select * from sys.columns c 
    where c.object_id = t.object_id and c.name = N'id'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.name AS ColName
     , t.name AS TableName
FROM sys.columns c INNER JOIN sys.tables t 
ON c.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
WHERE c.name LIKE '%ColumnName%' --<-- Column name you are looking for
```

Comment: What is "sys" over here?